# how do you set the width of an absolutely positioned div to 100% of its parent?

Tags: html, css

given the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>show stats</title>
    <style>
    span.main {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    div.stats {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:50px;
        background:black;
        color:white;
        padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;
        font-weight:500;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <span class="main">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/o2udo.jpg" alt="test" title="testpic"/>
      <div class="stats">
        <p>this is a caption</p>
      </div>
    </span>
    <span class="main">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/o2udo.jpg" alt="test" title="testpic"/>
      <div class="stats">
        <p>this is a caption</p>
      </div>
    </span>
    <span class="main">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/o2udo.jpg" alt="test" title="testpic"/>
      <div class="stats">
        <p>this is a caption</p>
      </div>
    </span>

  </body>

</html>
```

I want to make div.stats the width of the containing span.main. Setting the width to 100% doesn't work, because the resulting width exceeds the width of the container by the amount of the padding (30px).

I can fix it by setting the padding of div.stats to 0 and then padding the paragraph inside this div. This seems to work, but I suspect the way I'm doing it is dumb. Is there a cleaner way to position this div across the width of its container, while maintaining its vertical position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `left:0` and `right: 0` to `div.stats`:

```
div.stats {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;
    font-weight:500;
    left: 0;       /*Add this*/
    right: 0;      /*Add this*/
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sT9vA/1/**